# Get all objects from a GWT CellTable

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-celltable

Simple question: I have a CellTable filled with Keyword objects. Now, I would like to retrieve all the Keywords in that CellTable. Is this possible? If not, why? Surely there must be a way...

I can not understand how this is so hard (well maybe it isn't but I just can't seem find the answer for the life of me).

Some code to clarify:

```
//my celltable
private CellTable<Keyword> ctKeywordsLinked = new CellTable<Keyword>();

//listdataprovider to fill my celltable with
private ListDataProvider<Keyword> dataProviderLinkedKeywords = new ListDataProvider<Keyword>();

//add 4 keyword objects to the listdataprovider to fill the celltable
dataProviderLinkedKeywords.getList().add(new Keyword);
dataProviderLinkedKeywords.getList().add(new Keyword);
dataProviderLinkedKeywords.getList().add(new Keyword);
dataProviderLinkedKeywords.getList().add(new Keyword);
```

So now that I have my celltable filled, I would like to retrieve those 4 keywords without touching the listdataprovider. I hope everything is a bit more cleared up :-)

Comment: you want to get the update record from celltable?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by update record, but I have a Celltable with let's say 4 rows (which basically are 4 Keyword objects I added). 
Now I want to retrieve those 4 objects from the Celltable. I'll add some code to the original question to clearify things.

Comment: Why you need to get rows via CellTable? You can always get provider from it.

Comment: @cybersoft is it possible to get the listdataprovider from the celltable? Because I cannot find any methods that would do that. I'd expect something like this;  ctKeywordsLinked.getListDataProvider() or something, but that obviously doesn't work. Or are you referring to the dataProviderLinkedKeywords object itself? That is how I am doing it at the moment, but I don't really like it.

Comment: Sure, it is CellTable#getKeyProvider (ListDataProvider implements interface ProvidesKey), but you have to cast it to ListDataProvider. I'd just place this provider to the class field and use it later

Comment: Using the `ListDataProvider` is the intended way to get/set the data of a `CellTable`. It's its purpose, i.e. it hasn't been called 'data provider' just randomly.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks alot for the answers!
@cybersoft; if you could turn that comment into an answer i'd gladly accept it as such :)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: No, YOU don't use "thanks", I do ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CellTable` has method `getKeyProvider`, which returns object containing data under `ProvidesKey` interface.

You create ListDataProvider and pass it to cell table, so you can get that provider from cell table again at any time:

```
ListDataProvider provider = (ListDataProvider)cellTable.getKeyProvider();
provider.getList().get(0); // get first Keyword
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the 'provider' is 'null'